# Hello, i tried to write a trigger, when an account is created then contact record should also be created. But i am getting such error:

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
public class CallCreateNewContactTrigger {
    public Static void CreateContactMethod(List<Account> accList){
        List<Contact> conList= new List<Contact>();
        for(Account ac : accList){
            contact cc = new contact();
            cc.Lastname = ac.name;   
            cc.Id = ac.Id;
            conList.add(cc);
        }
        insert conList;
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Expected '{' but was:

Comment: Kanthi - There might be hidden chars causing this issue. Please manually type the code in IDE and it should work. I tried and i dont see any issues..

Answer (score 0):

Expected '{' but was: error is encountered when you miss '{' in your code. but all the opening and closing brackets are there in the code you shared.

I have found another error in your code i.e.

cc.Id = ac.Id;

Instead of this please use

cc.AccountId = ac.Id;

If my answer is helpful please mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

trigger Account_Con on Account (after insert) {

```
  if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert){      
      
      list<contact> conList = new list<contact>();
      
          for(Account a: trigger.new){
              
              contact c = new contact();
              c.LastName = a.Name;
              c.AccountId = a.Id;
              conList.add(c);
          }  
      if(conList.size()>0)
          insert conList;     
  }
```

}